# Обобщенный интерфейс, наследование

Tags: c#, generics

Господа, скажите, пожалуйста, почему в этом коде в методе Main() в качестве аргумента типа нельзя ставить тип "а"?

```
interface IZ<T> 
{
    T A { get; set; }
}
class a<T> : IZ<T>
{
    public T A { get; set; }
}
class b <T> : a<T>
{}
class c
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IZ<a> iz = new b<a>();
    }
}
```

Не могу понять причин, по которым этого нельзя сделать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что у вас нет такого типа а. У вас есть тип а<T>

Comment: Черт! Вот это я перегрелся... 
Спасибо.